# Load Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, autostart, support

Helo, i am jecute the instalation of mate `sudo apt install tasksel` and `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop` the firts err to start don't load the ubuntu for default, i use de ubuntu Errors and fount ok  the link of the instalcion : "https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mate-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux".

No show error in the terminal, use ubuntu to start normal show the screen black and block the mouse and block the keyboarth.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and attach any error output to the question (or to pastebin).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer i prove the `sudo apt-get update` it's ok and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop ^` it's ok but we not solve the problem, now load the logo of mate and show the screen black.

Comment: You have to try reinstallation of LightDM by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` .

Comment: No no fount, only access in recovery mode

Comment: i run `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`  and show `fsck de util-linux 2.34
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action`